# Get Reservation Utilization from AWS Cost explorer for multiple services

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk, aws-cost-explorer, aws-reserved-instances

How to get Reservations Utilization from AWS Cost explorer for both virtual machines and RDS at the same time?

I tried following code, but it throws error as we are allowed to pass only 1 service at a time.

```
final GetReservationUtilizationRequest request = new GetReservationUtilizationRequest()
           .withFilter(new Expression().
                withAnd(new Expression().
                    withDimensions(new DimensionValues()
                        .withKey("SERVICE").withValues("Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute")), new Expression()
                    .withDimensions(new DimensionValues()
                        .withKey("SERVICE").withValues("Amazon Relational Database Service"))))
                    .withGroupBy(Collections.singletonList(
                            new GroupDefinition()
                                    .withType("DIMENSION")
                                    .withKey("SUBSCRIPTION_ID")))
                    .withTimePeriod(new DateInterval()
                            .withStart(Objects.requireNonNull(startDate).format(ISO_LOCAL_DATE))
                            .withEnd(Objects.requireNonNull(endDate).format(ISO_LOCAL_DATE)));
```

This is current Request

Output:

**The following dimensions are filtered more than once: Service (Service: AWSCostExplorer; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 76e77a0b-ba13-44a1-a8f5-161146b9f8b0; Proxy: null)**

Comment: Status code 400 clearly means it's a validation error or issue with payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way to club services

```
final GetReservationUtilizationRequest request = new GetReservationUtilizationRequest()
           .withFilter(new Expression().
                    withDimensions(new DimensionValues()
                        .withKey("SERVICE").withValues("Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute", "Amazon Relational Database Service")))
                    .withGroupBy(Collections.singletonList(
                            new GroupDefinition()
                                    .withType("DIMENSION")
                                    .withKey("SUBSCRIPTION_ID")))
                    .withTimePeriod(new DateInterval()
                            .withStart(Objects.requireNonNull(startDate).format(ISO_LOCAL_DATE))
                            .withEnd(Objects.requireNonNull(endDate).format(ISO_LOCAL_DATE)));
```